# Rasa core restaurantbot demo example not working as expected

Tags: python, machine-learning, bots, rasa-nlu

I am learning rasa-core bot development.For understanding purpose, i have downloaded rasa restaurant bot example from [https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_core/tree/master/examples](http://rasa-core%20GitHub%20example) and run that example locally as per steps are given in the document.Below are steps

- python3 -m rasa_nlu.train -c nlu_model_config.json --fixed_model_name
  current
- python3 bot.py train-dialogue
- python3 bot.py run

After that it prompt

```
Bot loaded. Type a message and press enter :
Me-Hello
Bot-if you'd like to modify anything else, please tell me what
Me-moderately priced restaurant that serves creative food
Bot-if you'd like to modify anything else, please tell me what
```

For almost every message, bot is replying **"if you'd like to modify anything else, please tell me what
"** *and this message is picked from training dataset only.I am not typing anything from myself*.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I faced this problem today and only solution I have figured is that we have to type out intent like "/greet" for the bot to respond correctly. Don't understand where's the NLU is used then.